# My site is indexed in Google yet does not show in the SERPs

Tags: google, search-engine-indexing, search-engines, search-results

Please someone solve this mystery that has been plaguing me for months! All pages have been cached by Google recently yet still will not show up in a search. I'm guessing it's being penalized? How would I know/find out?

Index page & Web Design page both show up:
http://infin80.com
http://infin80.com/web-design/las-vegas-web-design.php

These 2 pages can not be found unless you put in "site:infin80.com" into Google:
http://infin80.com/logo-design/las-vegas-logos.php
http://infin80.com/print-design/las-vegas-graphic-design.php

I test it by quoting any line of text directly into Google such as the 1st line of copy on the logo page "Creating a small business brand is every bit as important for your small" and always get "No results found for..."

### Additional Part

All the webmaster tools are submitted properly with a sitemap (only 5 pages) and a robot.txt file that doesn't block any pages.

Why would one sub-page be indexed (web design) while the others are there if you put in the url "http://infin80.com/logo-design/las-vegas-logos.php" but not any of the text/images?!?

Answer (score 3):

One thing to be considered is Google simply does not consider those pages to be worthy of a good ranking. They may be considered low quality and rank poorly or not ranked at all as a result.

Answer (score 2):

You probably have lost some ranking.. Try getting some quality backlink  from high Pagerank site and see yourself springball in search results.

Answer (score 1):

**Look in the Google Webmaster Tools.** You will find plenty of information there including a tool to check how your pages are seen by the Googlebot.

Possibilities:

- robots.txt may be blocking indexing of those pages. You will see if this is the case under Crawl Errors.
- Googlebot is not seeing the content. You can test this by giving an exact URL see what the bot sees.
- That page has not been found due to lack of links, confusing links, etc. You can submit a sitemap through the Webmaster Tools to help the Googlebot.

Comment: For pages which cannot be found without use of the `site:` operator, however, one must also take into consideration the possibility that Google's servers have not finished categorizing the content for keyword or phrase searches.